# How can I simulate select onchange after first rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a **select** component within angular (5) with options created by **ngFor** and depending on the selected option, I hide/show some things on page.

To do this, I have defined **(change)** of select.

Every thing works when I change the selected option.

However, I want to do this even after first load of the web page, without having to click on Select and change the selected option.

So, I need to simulate (change) after first load of the page.

How could I do this?

```
<select (change)="onClick()">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.key}}</option>
</select>
```

***Edit**: I might have several cases of this. So I would like to have a "automatized" solution, rather than searching for every select components etc.

Comment: call onClick() in the component?

Answer (score 1):

Call `onClick()` inside the `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 0):

The Angular way to do this is using [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) with your select.

Component:

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  options = [
    {key: "one", value: "First option"},
    {key: "two", value: "Second option"},
    {key: "three", value: "Third option"}
  ];

  selectedOption = "one";
}
```

Template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" value="{{opt.key}}">{{ opt.value }}</option>
</select>
<p *ngIf="selectedOption === 'one'">First option selected</p>
etc.
```

Then, you can simply assign a new value to the `selectedOption` from your component code, and its template will update accordingly.

Check this quick example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxhbgp